# Make a list of dictionaries based on existing dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

Wrote a script to fetch list of instances run by each user on AWS. I got a list a dictionaries. I would like to sort and list the number of instances run by each user(`list_instances`).

```
list_instances=[{'type': u't2.small', 'user': u'user1'},
     {'type': u'm4.large', 'user': u'user1'},
     {'type': u't2.medium', 'user': u'user1'},
     {'type': u't2.small', 'user': u'user1'},
     {'type': u'm4.large', 'user': u'user1'},
     {'type': u't2.small', 'user': u'user1'},
     {'type': u'm4.large', 'user': u'user2'},
     {'type': u'm4.large', 'user': u'user3'},
     {'type': u't2.medium', 'user': u'user2'},
     {'type': u't2.medium', 'user': u'user2'},
     {'type': u't2.small', 'user': u'user3'}]
```

created a two lists with user name and instance type.

```
names_list=[u'user1', u'user2', u'ben', u'user3', u'user4']

type_list=[u't2.small', u'm4.large', u'm4.large', u't2.medium', u't2.small', u'm4.large', u'm4.large', u't2.small']
```

Try:

```
val = 0
final_instances=[]
for ii in names_list:
    temp_dic = {}
    for jj in type_list:
        for kk in list_instances:
            if (ii == kk['user']) and (jj in kk):
                #print ii,kk['user'],jj,kk,kk[jj]
                temp_dic['user']=kk['user']
                temp_dic[jj]=val+kk[jj]
                final_a.append(temp_dic)
print (final_instances)
```

I didn't get the expected output as like below. My logic not efficient to get the expected result. Can someone help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Goal:
`final_instances=
[{'user':u’user1’,’t2.small’:‘3’,’m4.large’:‘2’,’t2.medium’: ‘1’}
{'user': u’user2’,’m4.large’: ‘1’,’t2.medium’: ‘2’}
{'user': u’user3’,’t2.small’: ‘1’,’m4.large’: ‘1’}]`

Comment: Is there a particular reason `final_instances` is a list? Could it be a dictionary where the keys are the usernames and the values are a dictionary of types to counts?

Comment: Between the mixed accents and single quotes, and the missing brace, this code doesn't make it to execution.  Please post the accurate code.

Comment: Dictionary also fine as final_instances. I'm looking to find out `user1` has `n` number of instances of `type1`, `m` number of instances of `type2` ...so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to take counts after *grouping* your original list of dicts by user:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

f = itemgetter('user')
lst = []
for k, g in groupby(sorted(list_instances, key=f), f):
    c = Counter({u'user': k})
    c.update([d['type'] for d in g])
    lst.append(dict(c))

pprint(lst)
```

---

```
[{u'm4.large': 2, u't2.medium': 1, u't2.small': 3, u'user': u'user1'},
 {u'm4.large': 1, u't2.medium': 2, u'user': u'user2'},
 {u'm4.large': 1, u't2.small': 1, u'user': u'user3'}]
```

If you want the counts to end up as strings, you can use a *dictionary comprehension* to cast values in the counter before appending to the list.

```
...
d = {k: str(v) for k, v in c.items()}
lst.append(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make `final_instances` a dictionary instead of a list, and then each count into `int` instead of `str`:

```
final_instances = {}

for instance in list_instances:
    user = instance['user']
    type = instance['type']
    data = final_instances.get(user)
    if data is None:
        data = {}
        final_instances[user] = data
    count = data.get(type, 0)
    data[type] = count + 1
```

(Note that this uses the variable name `type` which shadows a Python builtin. I used it because that's the name of your field, but in my own code I change field names to never shadow builtins.)

At the end of this, you get `final_instances` as:

```
{
    'user1': {'m4.large': 2, 't2.medium': 1, 't2.small': 3},
    'user2': {'m4.large': 1, 't2.medium': 2},
    'user3': {'m4.large': 1, 't2.small': 1},
}
```